# Reading csv containing a list in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read this csv into pandas

```
HK,"[u'5328.1', u'5329.3', '2013-12-27 13:58:57.973614']"
HK,"[u'5328.1', u'5329.3', '2013-12-27 13:58:59.237387']"
HK,"[u'5328.1', u'5329.3', '2013-12-27 13:59:00.346325']"
```

As you can see there are only 2 columns and the second one is a list, is there a way to interpret it correctly ( meaning reading the values in the list as columns) when using **pd.read_csv()** with arguments ?

thank you

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One option is to use `ast.literal_eval` as converter:

```
>>> import ast
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None, quotechar='"', sep=',', 
...                   converters={1:ast.literal_eval})
>>> df
    0                                             1
0  HK  [5328.1, 5329.3, 2013-12-27 13:58:57.973614]
1  HK  [5328.1, 5329.3, 2013-12-27 13:58:59.237387]
2  HK  [5328.1, 5329.3, 2013-12-27 13:59:00.346325]
```

And convert those lists to a DataFrame if needed, for example with:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df[1].tolist(), index=df[0],
...                           columns=list('ABC')).reset_index()
>>> df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'])
>>> df
    0       A       B                          C
0  HK  5328.1  5329.3 2013-12-27 13:58:57.973614
1  HK  5328.1  5329.3 2013-12-27 13:58:59.237387
2  HK  5328.1  5329.3 2013-12-27 13:59:00.346325
```

Comment: similar to what I had ( `pd.read_csv(dtype={'a': str, 'b': list})`) from the [read_csv() documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) however it doesn't put the values of the list into columns as requested.

Comment: This is helpful, although I'm wondering if I should massage the csv file a bit better ( ie getting the columns clean ) before parsing it with Pandas .

Comment: @Ewan : Did that really work for you? For me, it says : dtype <class 'list'> not understood

Comment: If your dataset is huge you may have performance issues when using `eval`

Answer (score 15):

```
df['new_column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

Just run the above code on the column containing list as string.

Answer (score 3):

Based alko's answer, you can use the df.apply() function for the first part to read the actual data in the list string:

```
 >>> df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None,sep=',')
 >>> df
     0                                                  1
  0  HK  [u'5328.1', u'5329.3', '2013-12-27 13:58:57.97...
  1  HK  [u'5328.1', u'5329.3', '2013-12-27 13:58:59.23...
  2  HK  [u'5328.1', u'5329.3', '2013-12-27 13:59:00.34...
 >>> df[1] = df[1].apply(eval)
 >>> df
     0                                             1
  0  HK  [5328.1, 5329.3, 2013-12-27 13:58:57.973614]
  1  HK  [5328.1, 5329.3, 2013-12-27 13:58:59.237387]
  2  HK  [5328.1, 5329.3, 2013-12-27 13:59:00.346325]
```

Comment: Be careful with this, `eval` executes arbitrary python code contained within these cells which is a huge **security risk**. See: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Answer (score 1):

use .strip() in python.

```
with open(csvfile, 'r')as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        col1 = row[0]
        col2 = row[1:].strip("[]")
```