# Shapely loop not creating Linestring

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

I'm attempting to convert tuples from a dataframe into a linestring. This is part of my dataframe imported from a csv file.

```
   Unnamed: 0      name     route                                              decode
0           0    Funshine!  ofosF|mqaShJ@?rLh@d@veCIVd@LbEJfJ^f@lE?Rp@^L~g...  '[(-105.28, 39.999), (-105.282, 39.998), (-105.282, 39.99), (-105.28, 39.995), (-105.282, 39.99), (etc)]'
```

If I manually copy and paste the contents of the decode column into the LineString() condition, it converts it. The error I receive is posted below.

```
line = LineString(df.decode[0])
print(line)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx", line 86, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/taylo/PycharmProjects/PermitProj/Polyline Decode.py", line 20, in <module>
    line = LineString(df.decode[1])
  File "C:\Users\taylo\Miniconda3\envs\ExcelPermitExe\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._set_coords(coordinates)
  File "C:\Users\taylo\Miniconda3\envs\ExcelPermitExe\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 97, in _set_coords
    ret = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
  File "shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx", line 166, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py
AssertionError
```

I eventually would like to loop it, so I set it to the dataframe column decode. This is the loop that I've created to eventually write the linestring to the column.

```
def linestringdecode(name, decode):
    try:
        return LineString(decode)
    except:
        print(name)
        return np.nan

df['decode'] = df.apply(lambda x: linestringdecode(x[1], x[3]), axis=1)
```

How do I write this so that I avoid this error and can convert the tuples to a column in my dataframe?

Comment: Hi could you provide your sample data as a dict? As in the current format its hard to read/understand as well as to import. Pandas has a convenient method for this the `df.to_dict()`.

Comment: It's a large output but it's essentially this,  [118, 'Up Bear, Green, down to bike', '{icsFbaraS`AGqCPvWeAvBTpDlBnBj@tBtAnAjAbE`G^CbA~ClBlBdAj@c@uA?s@~@cCXeCl@Sx', '[(-105.28, 39.99), (-105.28, 39.99), (-105.28, 39.99), (-105.28, 39.99), (-105.282, 39.99), (the list has about 50 or so more pairs)]'

Comment: So the decode column contains multiple tuples (with coordinates) however the total data frame has only one row? Or are there more rows like this?

Comment: There are about 500 rows similar to this one

Comment: I found a solution and edited my answer. Please not that I had to change the column passed to the `linestringdecode` to the index 4 in order to correctly pass the `decode` column as an argument. Please check if this holds true for your case as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found in this section.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358068/converting-to-linestring-using-dataframe-column/

```
df['decode'] = df.decode.apply(lambda row: LineString(eval(row)))
```

Edit: eval() is dangerous to use. Make sure you're using trusted data.

Comment: Absolutely @BjörnB!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit final solution**

After some clearing up it  turns out that the column `decode` is saved as a string `"[(1,1),(2,3),(4,4),(1,3)]"`which first needs to be converted to a list of tuples. After converting with a dense list comprehension the LineString conversion works as supposed to

```
df['decode'] = [eval(ele) for ele in df.decode.str.strip()[:]]
df['decode'] = df.apply(lambda x: linestringdecode(x[1], x[4]), axis=1)
```

**Alternative** Another option to go about this, is to already fix the import. By converting the string directly to list of tuples directly with the help of the `ast.literal_eval`, as suggested in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799593/reading-csv-containing-a-list-in-pandas/44607092)

```
import ast
df = pd.read_csv("Test_Csv_With_List.csv", quotechar='"', sep=",",converters={4:ast.literal_eval})
```

**Before Edit:** 
I tried to reproduce your error with the code below. However it runs through perfectly fine without any error.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import pandas as pd

def linestringdecode(name, decode):
    try:
        return LineString(decode)
    except:
        print(name)
        return np.nan

data = {'Unamed 0': [0,1],
        'name': ['test','test2'],
        'rote': ['Gibberish','moreGib'],
        'decode': [[(-105.27983, 40.06008), (-105.27984, 40.05827)],[(-23, 23), (-22, 24)]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# print(df)
df['decode'] = df.apply(lambda x: linestringdecode(x[1], x[3]), axis=1)
```

From your error message `AttributeError: 'str'` I think I can deduct that something is wrong with the import of your data. My Assumption is, that decode has the dtype Object rather than list.

**Please validate** that the passed argument `decode` to the function `linestringdecode()` is of type list and not string.

Comment: I did notice that your decode data has two points followed by brackets. Mine is more in the line of [(-105.27983, 40.06008), (-105.27984, 40.05827), (-23, 23), (-22, 24) (etc)]. Not sure if that would change things.

Comment: So these 4 tuples would be equivalent to 4 rows in your dataframe? `(-105.27983, 40.06008), (-105.27984, 40.05827), (-23, 23), (-22, 24)`